# Disable new relic on certain page

Tags: 8

I am trying to disable new relic on custom form. The standard way of disabling the new relic injection is:

```
if (extension_loaded('newrelic')) {
   newrelic_disable_autorum();
}
```

I am using hook_page_attachment to disable new relic javascript before the page renders:

```
mymodule_page_attachments(array &$attachments){
if (extension_loaded('newrelic')) {
   newrelic_disable_autorum();
 }
}
```

The above solution doesn't work. Is any one have similar problem and know the work around.

Comment: You probably want [hook_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8.2.x).

Comment: @Neograph734    Your solution works like charm!